# How can I use a Perl script to create the plain text file

Tags: perl, verilog

How can use a Perl script to create the plain text file. Perl should generate (random 16 bit hex) input data.

Comment: Go read the documentation for [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

If you are new to Perl take a look at http://learn.perl.org

Check out [Open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html), and [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 3):

[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a file handle, then [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) to it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other advice, to generate a random value, use Perl's [rand](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) function.

The Perl documentation can also be queried at your command prompt.  For example, to access the FAQ:

```
perldoc -q random
```